# Best way to remove thousand separators from string amount using a regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, separator

I have variables that contain amounts and would like to remove the (US) thousand separators but also have to cover the scenario that there may be non-US formatted amounts where the comma is used for the decimals instead of for the thousands where I don't want to replace the comma.

**Examples:**

- 1,234,567.00 needs to become 1234567.00
- 1,234.00 needs to become 1234.00
  but
- 1.234.567,00 needs to remain unchanged as not US format (i.e. comma here is used for decimals)
- 1.234,00 needs to remain unchanged as not US format (i.e. comma here is used for decimals)

I was thinking of using the following but wasn't sure about it as I am pretty new to Regex:

```
myVar.replace(/(\d+),(?=\d{3}(\D|$))/g, "$1");
```

What is best solution here? Note: I just need to cover normal amounts like the above examples, no special cases like letter / number combinations or things like 1,2,3 etc.

Comment: Will you always have 2 decimals? If not, then you will never know whether 1,234 is 1000 + 234 or 1 + 0.234

Comment: for me, this worked: ,(?=\d{3})

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This one may suit your needs:

```
,(?=[\d,]*\.\d{2}\b)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GydzBIqYZWx35JIz)

Comment: Thanks for this - wouldnt I need to wrap this in / /g to cover all instances of thousand separators ?

Comment: thank you for the Debuggex Demo web site, never seen it before really great one the with the graph.

Comment: @user2571510 Yes, you'll have to enable the `global` flag: `/theregex/g`.

Comment: Thanks, All - this works very well and I like the workflow image.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (string.match(/\.\d{2}$/) {
    string = string.replace(',', '');
}
```

or

```
string.replace(/,(?=.*\.\d+)/g, '');
```

Comment: Thanks - I would like to avoid using IF statements here.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `replace()` method to remove all the commas. They will be replaced with an empty string. I'm using reg exp with lookahead assertion to detect if a comma is followed by three digits, if so given comma will be removed.

```
string.replace(/,(?=\d{3})/g, '')
```

Examples:

```
'12,345,678.90'.replace(/,(?=\d{3})/g, '')
// '12345678.90'

'1,23,456.78'.replace(/,(?=\d{3})/g, '')
// '1,23456.78'

'$1,234.56'.replace(/,(?=\d{3})/g, '')
// '$1234.56'
```

Comment: This answer worked for me

Comment: This works until you have Argentine Peso ARS 
'1.222,222'.replace(/,(?=\d{3})/g, '') evaluates to '1.222222'

Answer (score 2):

Replace `/,(?=\d*[\.,])/g` with empty string?

http://regexr.com/39v2m

Comment: Thanks for this as well ! I am trying to understand what makes the most sense here for me.

Answer (score 1):

This code is worked for me and you can use it in set amount val for remove separators

```
t.replace(/,(?=\d{3})/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

myVar = myVar.replace(/([.,])(\d\d\d\D|\d\d\d$)/g,'$2');

Removes the period . or comma , when used as a thousand separator.

Comment: How to do this in sql query analyzer using Find/Replace and regex