# How to remove thousand separator and decimal from string using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to remove thousand separator and decimal from string value?

EX: 100,000.00, I want this to be 100000

In my code removing thousand separate is working find but need to remove decimal too

```js
$scope.convertToNumber = function(val) {
  var removedThousand = "";

  if (typeof val === 'string') {
    removedThousand = val.replace(/,/g, '');

    return removedThousand;
  } else {
    return val;
  }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to remove thousand separators from string amount using a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105755/best-way-to-remove-thousand-separators-from-string-amount-using-a-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Javascript functions

```
Math.floor() (round down)
Math.ceil() (round up)
Math.round()
```

like

```
$scope.convertToNumber = function (val) {
    var removedThousand = "";

    if(typeof val === 'string'){
        removedThousand = val.replace(/,/g, '');
        Math.floor(removedThousand);
        return removedThousand;
    }else {
        return val;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string on the decimal and only take the first value from the array. This can be chained onto what you already have.

```
removedThousand = val.replace(/,/g, '').split('.')[0];
```